# Python round float results

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, rounding, floating

in python I noticed that sometimes it returns round result which I do not want.
If I divide 94192*100/86400 I would like to get as result `109.01` (on two decimal places for full result 109,0185185185185) while I am always getting `109.02`. Is this possible to have ? Thaks

```
numberOfSeconds=94192
percentagePerDay=round(float(numberOfSeconds*100)/86400,2)
#desired result 
print (percentagePerDay)
```

Comment: you probably know about the `decimal` module in python? right?

Comment: math module has the 'floor' function

Comment: @JoeyMallone I am not aware about decimal module. Can you explain?

Comment: On this page [pythondocs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html), `CTRL+F` for `Decimal` and you will find the relevant info.